# How can i create custom validation in django model forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a custom form validation in Django forms. I am able to do it normal Django forms but unable to do it in model forms.
my Django form code is

```
class Post_Article(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label = 'Title',max_length = 100)
    abstract = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 300)
    body = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ImageField(required = False)
    hash_tags = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required = False)

    def no_of_hash_tags(self):
        cleaned_data = super().no_of_hash_tags()
        tags = cleaned_data.get('hash_tags')

        if tags:
            tags = split(str(tags))
            if len(tags) > 5:
                raise forms.ValiadationError('Maximum 5 tags are allowed')
```

the Django model is

```
class PostsArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default= timezone.now)
    abstract = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=('images/'),blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    hash_tags = models.CharField(max_length = 50,blank=  True)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def summary(self):
        return self.absract[:200]

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def link_tags(self):
        cleaned_data = super().link_tags
        tags = cleaned_data.get['hash_tags']

        for tag in tags:
            hashing(tag,"PostsArticle")
```

After some discussion on stack overflow I updates my Django forms to

```
class Post_Article(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label = 'Title',max_length = 100)
    abstract = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 300)
    body = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ImageField(required = False)
    hash_tags = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = PostsArticle
        fields=("title", "abstract", "body", "image", "hash_tags")

        def clean(self)
        :
         cleaned_data=super(Post_Article, self).clean()
         tags = cleaned_data.get("hash_tags")
         if tags:
            tags = split(str(tags))
            if len(tags) > 5:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Maximum 5 tags are allowed')
         return cleaned_data
```

Now I am unable to get how can I use it with my current class used in views.py

```
class FeedUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin , UpdateView):
    model = FeedPosts
    fields= ['body', 'image']
    template_name= 'post/edit_Feed.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        Posts = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == Posts.user:
            return True
        return False
```

I want to use my Django forms code instead of creating view from my model directly. I want to do it because I want to have some custom validation of a field as given in my forms code

kindly help how can I add form validation to my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning a specific field attribute, you would have to call `clean_<field_name>`.

```
class Post_ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostsArticle
        fields = ['abstract', 'title', 'body', 'image', 'hash_tags']

    def clean_hash_tags(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean_hash_tags()
        tags = self.cleaned_data.get('hash_tags')
        if tags:
            tags = split(str(tags))
            if len(tags) > 5:
                raise forms.ValiadationError('Maximum 5 tags are allowed')
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Can you help me how to implement it further as my current implementation is class 
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = PostsArticle
    fields= ['title', 'abstract', 'body', 'hash_tags', 'image' ]
    print(Post_Article().fields)
    #fields =
    template_name= 'post/post.html'



    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        print(form.instance.user)
        return super().form_valid(form) the proper code I is in the answers to this question by me

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `clean` method for your `ModelForm`.

**Example:**

```
class Post_Article(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    hash_tags = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required = False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = PostsArticle
        fields=("title", "abstract", "body", "image", "hash_tags",)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super(Post_Article, self).clean()
        tags = cleaned_data.get("hash_tags")
        if tags:
            tags = split(str(tags))
            if len(tags) > 5:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Maximum 5 tags are allowed')
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: @user140446 you also need to import your model here like this: `from example.models import PostsArticle`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this is the name of his model

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer - there are hooks for validating individual fields (cf rossi's answer), `Form.clean()` is supposed to be used for cross-validation (when one field depends on another)

Comment: @vadimb yes I saw this afterwards and deleted my comment ;-)

Comment: Can you help me how to implement it further as my current implementation is class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = PostsArticle
    fields= ['title', 'abstract', 'body', 'hash_tags', 'image' ]
    print(Post_Article().fields)
    #fields =
    template_name= 'post/post.html'



    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        print(form.instance.user)
        return super().form_valid(form) the proper code I is in the answers to this question by me

Answer (score 0):

the clean funtion is not getting invoked
Django forms is

```
class Post_Article(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label = 'Title',max_length = 100)
    abstract = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea, max_length = 300)
    body = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ImageField(required = False)
    hash_tags = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = PostsArticle
        fields=("title", "abstract", "body", "image", "hash_tags")

        def clean(self):
            print(hello)
            cleaned_data=super(Post_Article, self).clean()
            tags = cleaned_data.get("hash_tags")
            if tags:
              tags = split(str(tags))
              if len(tags) > 5:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Maximum 5 tags are allowed')
            return cleaned_data
```

the clean funtion is not getting invoked

the formview for the same is

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = Post_Article
    template_name= 'post/post.html'
    success_url =  '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        print(form.instance.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

the formview is in the views.py